# What is the logic for searching nested objects in Java?

Tags: java, search, data-structures

I have a object structure for Person as below and I want to search a Person on the based of his name.

```
public Person{

   String name;

   List<Person> person;

}
```

How can we implement search method for this?

There will be one root object which is Person and it has link to other persons and so on.

And the names of Persons are unique.

The search signature could be

```
public Person findPerson(Person root, String name){

}
```

I can look it as [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

Can anyone suggest any other solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need recursion. Iterate over all the persons in the List and search within that person for the same target. Once you found your target, return and stop all searching.

Here is some pseudo code:

```
Person search(Person, Name)
    if (Person.Name == Name) return Person;
    for each subPerson in Person.person:
        Person found = subPerson.search(Person, Name);
        if (found != null) return found;
    return null;
```

Comment: Is that possible without recursion?

Comment: But is recursion a good practice? I personally do not see anything other that recursion as a good solution for this problem.

Comment: You have a recursive data structure, so recursion seems natural. In extreme cases you might have a data structure that's, say, very "tall" the stack requirements then might then get excessive. However, in your problem I'd use recursion until I find a good reason not to.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need to visit every person, and every person each person holds, this is easily implemented using a recursive algorithm, which is therefore depth first.

One thing to consider: do you know that names are unique? If not you'll need to return a list of matching Persons, and that might be mopre appropriate if you want to do, say, a pattern match on the name: all people whose surname is "Smith"

Answer (score 0):

You coul use reflection. At runtime check if an instance of Person has a variable of type Person and then call its getter. Do it recursevly to minimize and optimize the code.

Comment: I could not understand the use of reflection here.

Comment: Why should reflection be used? Every person has already a member pointing to a list of persons. Cycles in the relationships of those persons are an issue. Using reflection for that kind of problem is just inefficient